# Assets 2.1.1 - No S3 Thumbnails!

Tags: assets, s3

Using Assets 2.1.1 with a single S3 source.

All images are displaying correctly on the front-end, but no thumbnails are viewable in the Assets file sheet. All of the images are indexed, and the default thumbnail placeholder is sized to the same dimensions as the actual image, but no visible thumbnail.

I don't think this is an Assets bug, as it was working previously. In order to track it down thought, I'm wondering the following:

- Are Assets thumbnails for an S3 source generated and stored locally or the S3 source?
- I'm thinking this is permissions related, but not sure if it's local or on the S3 source.

Any info or advice here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Synergerna - are you seeing any JS errors in your browser's debug console?  Also, can you make sure that /system/expressionengine/cache and its assets subfolders are 777 and the correct group/owner permissions? Thank you!

Comment: Hey Lisa, No JS errors, so I think that's a good sign. Checking permissions on the `cache` directories now. I'll report back on that. But, I think that does answer my broader question of where thumbnails are actually stored? It's sounding like S3 asset thumbnails are stored locally?